# SVG stroke url: linearGradient is working but solidColor is not

Tags: html, svg

I've tried to set the stroke color. It works using `linearGradient` but it doesn't work using [`solidColor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#SolidColorElement):

```
<svg class="svg_defs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="color_1">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="red" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <solidColor id="color_2" solid-color="blue" solid-opacity="1"/>

        <linearGradient id="half">
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="green" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="green" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-2 -2 101 101" width="50">
    <rect x="0" width="49%" height="99%" fill="url(#half)" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#color_1)"/>
    <rect x="50%" width="49%" height="99%" fill="url(#half)" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#color_2)"/>
</svg>
```

The `rect` referencing `color_1` is working, but not the second one referencing `color_2`. Even the [example on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/examples/solidcolor.svg) isn't working. The link should show forms in red. This happens (or doesn't happen) in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Is there something missing?

**Try it:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xhrnmwe/)

Comment: Is there something missing? Like that I would say browser implementation, but I'm not sure though. It seems that `<solidColor>` is part of the SVGTiny1.2 specification don't know how browsers support it today...

Comment: @Kaiido I didn't notice that this is *1.2*. Well that might be the problem for the missing browser implementation.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_stroke0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solidColor is not part of SVG 1.1, it is part of SVG 1.2 tiny and in a slightly altered and non-backwards compatible way it's proposed to be part of the upcoming SVG 2 specification.

I've a [patch](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1177032) for Firefox that would implement solidColor but the only other UA that ever supported this was the now obsolete Opera version 12.

solidColor seems rather unnecessary given that it can be emulated either with a single stop gradient or via CSS variables. If you can persuade some other UAs to consider implementing it my Firefox patch can land.

Answer (score 0):

SolidColor isn't support by any browser. It's also mentioned in the svg2 working draft, but I don't have a clue when it will be implemented.

Alternative you could use:

```
<rect x="50%" width="49%" height="99%" fill="url(#half)" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" stroke-opacity="1"/>
```

or

```
    <linearGradient id="color_2">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
```